# Android Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"url", local:"scope"). Expected elements are &lt;{

Tags: android, unmarshalling, ksoap

I am trying to consume `SOAP` webservices in `Android` and writing own code for doing so:
Below is my code

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addSoapObject(getScopeBean());
request.addSoapObject(getLocaleBean());
request.addProperty("commercialRef","somevalidvalue" );

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
     SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
String xsd = envelope.XSD;
Log.e("envelop ", xsd);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 2000);
http.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
String requestDump = http.requestDump;
Log.e("requestDump", requestDump);

String responseDump = http.responseDump;
Log.e("responseDump", responseDump);
```

My request xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
<v:Header /><v:Body>
<someMethodname xmlns="NAMESPACE" >
<scope>
<brand>
somevalidname
</brand>
<country>
WW
</country>
<project>
somevalidname
</project>
</scope>
<locale>
<isoCountry>
GB
</isoCountry>
<isoLanguage>en</isoLanguage>
</locale>
<commercialRef>somevalidname</commercialRef>
</getProductDetailByCommercialRef>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

and response is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
<soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element 
(uri:"http://", local:"scope").
Expected elements are &lt;{}rangeId>,&lt;{}scope>,&lt;{}commercialRef>,&lt;{}locale> 
</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have been tryin to fix it from 3 days and no success. Can anybody please help in fixin it. I would be great. 
In soap ui the wsdl works fine.
In wsdl file the method

```
<wsdl:message name="getXXXXXXXXX">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getProductDetailByCommercialRef" name="parameters" />
```

I have confirmed methodname, namespace, url which i gave is correct.
If anybody gets what I am doing incorrect way. Please suggest.

Thanks,
Android developer

Answer (score 0):

change your request to the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope ... xmlns:ord="NAMESPACE">
...
<ord:someMethodname>
```

Answer (score 0):

when sending a xml thorugh SOAP you have to include

```
<![CDATA[
  <your xml items>
  </your xml items>
]]>
```